# Persist Quarkus devservices database

Tags: quarkus, docker-volume

Is there a way of persisting [Quarkus devservices databases](https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services)? Maybe a way of using volumes, but I can not find any reference. I am thinking on something like a property (non existing) `quarkus.datasource.devservices.volume=some_volume` that will reuse `some_volume` existing volume with the spin Docker container.

Comment: There isn't anything provided by Quarkus toward that end

Comment: Thanks @geoand for the reply, I turned the question into a feature request in case Quarkus community find it useful: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/30595

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you can do for now is, disable database startup from dev-services (see link 3 below) and add a QuarkusTestResource on your test class and startup your own docker image with a volume mount to your disk.

And the next time you startup your test, the data should be available as long as it points to the same volume mount. Also make sure that you don't use TestTransaction, otherwise the transaction will be rollbacked at the end of the test.

Maybe these links can help you:

[cheat sheat: continious testing](https://lordofthejars.github.io/quarkus-cheat-sheet/#_continuous_testing)

[cheat sheat: dev-services](https://lordofthejars.github.io/quarkus-cheat-sheet/#_dev_services)

[dev-service guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't refer to data to be used in tests, but in development.

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services#quarkus-datasource-config-group-dev-services-build-time-config_quarkus.datasource.devservices.container-properties-container-properties